# TSQL replace([my_string],'NULL',NULL) still returns NULL when [my_string] does not contain the string 'NULL'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Scenario:
For whatever reason, you discover a table with columns that contain the literal characters 'NULL' but they should actually contain a real `NULL`. So you decide to update the 'NULL' to `NULL`. To wit:

```
       IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_nulls') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #my_nulls;
   SELECT 1 as id
          ,'NULL' as my_column
     INTO #my_nulls
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 as id
          ,'to the man with a hammer' as my_column
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 as id
          ,'everything looks like a' as my_column
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 as id
          ,'NULL' as my_column
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT id
          ,my_column
          ,replace(my_column,'NULL',NULL)  as nullified
     FROM #my_nulls
```

Here's the possibly surprising answer:

```
  id | my_column                | nullified
---- |------------------------- |-------------
   1 | NULL                     | NULL
   2 | to the man with a hammer | NULL
   3 | everything looks like a  | NULL
   4 | NULL                     | NULL
```

So why have row 2 and 3 been converted to `NULL` when they clearly don't contain the string 'NULL' 
I think I know the answer to this but I'm asking for a few reasons:

1. I could easily be wrong :-)
2. I can't see this specific question/answer with reference to `replace()` on Stack Overflow, AND
3. Others may be scratching their heads too AND
4. I didn't read BOL properly the first time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I eventually discovered is that the reason the strings are getting converted to NULLs is that NULL is an undefined value. You can't create knowledge out of nothing.
Anything compared with `NULL` returns `NULL` and the `REPLACE` function is no exception. [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) says

> "...Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL...."

To get around this problem I replaced `REPLACE` with the `NULLIF` expression.  So:

```
   SELECT id
          ,my_column
          ,nullif(my_column,'NULL')  as nullified
     FROM #my_nulls
```

Returns:

```
  id | my_column                | nullified
-----|--------------------------|-------------------------
   1 | NULL                     | NULL
   2 | to the man with a hammer | to the man with a hammer
   3 | everything looks like a  | everything looks like a
   4 | NULL                     | NULL
```

Comment: Yeah `nullif` would have been my suggestion too. Alternatively you could have done `iif(my_column = 'NULL', null, my_column)`. No reason to in this case, but useful to think about if you run into future null issues like this.